# Akka. How to mock child actors in java?

Tags: java, akka

Let's say I have a parent actor who creates Actor by himself.

```
public static class Parent extends UntypedActor {

private ActorRef child = context().actorOf(Props.create(Child.class));

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        // do some stuff
        child.tell("some stuff", self());
    }
}

public static class Child extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

How can I mock this child Actor? Google didn't give me any reasonable results. I've been told by Akka's documentation that creating an actor is a good practice. But how can I follow this practice if I can't even test my actors?

Comment: The title of the question sounds a lil dramatic.

Answer (score 1):

I use probes as described in this answer to a similar question:

[How to mock child Actors for testing an Akka system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196907/how-to-mock-child-actors-for-testing-an-akka-system)

```java
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();

new JavaTestKit( system )
{{
  final JavaTestKit probe = new JavaTestKit( system );
  final Props props = Props.create( SupervisorActor.class );

  final TestActorRef<SupervisorActor> supervisorActor =
    TestActorRef.create( system, props, "Superman" );

  supervisorActor.tell( callCommand, getTestActor() );

  probe.expectMsgEquals(42);
  assertEquals(getRef(), probe.getLastSender());
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be written in Scala, but I guess that same should apply to Java. The answer is that you could use TestProbe to mock your child actor. Let's take this example:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}

class Parent extends Actor {
  import Parent._

  val child = context.actorOf(Child.props)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case TellName(name) => child ! name
    case Reply(msg) => sender() ! msg
  }
}

object Parent {
  case class TellName(name: String)
  case class Reply(text: String)
  def props = Props(new Parent)
}

class Child extends Actor {
  override def receive: Actor.Receive = {
    case name: String => sender !  Parent.Reply(s"Hi there $name")
  }
}

object Child {
  def props = Props(new Child)
}
```

So, we have a `Parent` actor that sends a message `TellName` to a `Child` actor. After receiving a message `Child` actor will respond by sending a `Reply` message with content to its sender - i.e. "Hi there Joe". Now, this is a test:

```
class ParentSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("test")) with WordSpecLike with Matchers with ImplicitSender {


  val childProbe = TestProbe()

  "Parent actor" should {
    "send a message to child actor" in {
      childProbe.setAutoPilot(new AutoPilot {
        override def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any): AutoPilot = msg match {
          case name: String => sender ! Reply(s"Hey there $name")
            NoAutoPilot
        }
      })
      val parent = system.actorOf(Props(new Parent {
        override val child = childProbe.ref
      }))
      parent ! TellName("Johnny")
      childProbe.expectMsg("Johnny") // Message received by a test probe
      expectMsg("Hey there Johnny") // Reply message
    }
  }
}
```

Now, to mock behavior of our `Child` actor, we can use `setAutoPilot` method to define how it would reply after receiving specific kind of message. In our case, let's say if `Child` actor receives String type of message "Jonny", it will respond with a `Reply` message that has a content "Hey there Johnny".
First, we send `TellName` with content "Johnny". Then we can assert what message our mock actor received - `childProbe.expectMsg("Johnny")`. After that we can assert reply message - `expectMsg("Hey there Johnny")`. Notice that reply message will be "Hey there Johnny" and not "Hi there Johnny" which corresponds to our altered behavior as defined in mocked `Child` actor.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several approaches](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html#testing-parent-child-relationships) you can take in order to mock the Child actor. One of them is to externalize code for child creation from parent actor.

In order to do it, you need to rewrite your Parent actor and pass it a function that will create your Child actor:

Note: we will use `AbstractActor` instead of `UntypedActor` due to [deprecation in version 2.5.0](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html).

```
public class Parent extends AbstractActor {

  private final ActorRef child;

  public Parent(Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childCreator) {
    this.child = childCreator.apply(getContext());
  }

  public static Props props(Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childCreator) {
    return Props.create(Parent.class, childCreator);
  }

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .matchEquals("send ping", s -> child.tell("ping", getSelf()))
        .match(String.class, System.out::println)
        .build();
  }
}
```

Your Child actor will stay the same:

```
public class Child extends AbstractActor {

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .matchEquals("ping", s -> getSender().tell("pong", getSelf()))
        .build();
  }
}
```

Now in your test you can use probe actor reference to test the message that should be sent to `Child` actor i.e. `probe` will act as `Child` actor mock:

```
public class ParentTest {

  static ActorSystem system;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass() {
    system = ActorSystem.create();
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDownClass() {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
    system = null;
  }

  @Test
  public void givenParent_whenSendPing_thenPingChild() {
    TestKit probe = new TestKit(system);

    Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childCreator = arf -> probe.getRef();

    ActorRef parentActor = system.actorOf(Parent.props(childCreator));

    probe.send(parentActor, "send ping");

    probe.expectMsgEquals("ping");
  }
}
```

So, instead of using (would be used in real application code):

```
Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childCreator = arf -> arf
                                      .actorOf(Props.create(Child.class));
```

we are going to use:

```
Function<ActorRefFactory, ActorRef> childCreator = arf -> probe.getRef();
```

and check if `probe` received a "ping" message.

Hope it helps. More info about given approach can be found [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/testing.html#externalize-child-making-from-the-parent).